# Should I make my raytracer with GLSL or OpenCL, and how I do I get a large 1gb buffer?

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, opencl, shader

Right now, I have implemented a GLSL raytracer that uses a buffer texture to access the acceleration structure used for ray tracing.

I'm traversing the texture with a while loop, and it's very costly, but I think there's hope for making it faster. But there seems to be a wall that I'm going to hit that I can't seem to fix. Buffer textures have a limited size, on my GPU it was around 200mb, I forget exactly what it was.

I need my data structure to be around 1gb.

Someone recommended OpenCL to me to solve the problem, so I studied OpenCL and now I'm familiar with the API. However, I discovered that OpenCL also has a similar problem with maximum buffer sizes. Most GPUs will only give you access to 1/4 of total vram in a single buffer. Most GPU's have 1 or 2 gbs of vram so creating 1 buffer for my structure will not work.

It seems like the only way get my data structure on the GPU is to split it up into multiple buffers now. My question is, what's the most effective and fast way to do this, and would it wise to continue in OpenCL or GLSL. I know branching buffer/texture reads can be costly, and it seems like that's what I would have to do if I split it up. You could avoid the branch if you somehow put the buffer to read in an array and index the buffer somehow, however, I have experienced indexing with GLSL to be EXTREMELY slow, even if it's just indexing a local array (why is this?). I wonder if the same slowness would occur if you grouped buffers into an array in a kernel, if that's even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current devices with updated drivers can access more than that. AMD has an envvar that lets you set it even higher.

OpenCL could be a good solution for you.

Also, OpenGL 4.3 added Compute Shaders which are extremely OpenCL-like and perfect for folks with OpenGL experience and an existing OpenGL application.

Regarding performance, looping in your kernel can be a problem due to work group divergence, and if you don't have *many* work items active, it can reduce device occupancy.

Comment: +1 for OpenGL 4.3 and the compute shader. I updated my 2yo fluid simulator from 3 pairs of vertex/fragment shaders to one single compute shader => faster and more flexible.